# Finite series: order of terms

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I know that $\sum_{i=1}^\infty h_i<\infty$. I also know that $h_i>0$ (in fact, also that $h_i<1$).

Can I conclude that $h_i=O(i^a)$ for some $a<-1$? EDIT: For $a=-1$?

I am aware that if $h_i\sim i^a$, $a<-1$, then $\sum_{i=1}^\infty h_i<\infty$. My question concerns the "opposite" direction, so to speak.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $a<-1$, the answer is no : take
$$h_i = \frac{1}{i \ln^2(i)}$$

For $a=-1$, the answer is also no. You can consider, for example,
$$
h_i = \left\{
    \begin{array}{ll}
       \frac{1}{\sqrt{i}} & \mbox{if } i \text{ is a power of } 2\\
        \frac{1}{i^2} & \mbox{otherwise.}
    \end{array}
\right.
$$

However, if $a=-1$ and if $(h_i)$ is decreasing, then the answer is yes !

Comment: Thanks - could you take a look at my edit?

Comment: @ChristophHanck I edited !